# Connecting Lagom to external Kafka Server (on Confluent Cloud)

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, lagom

I need to connect Lagom 1.6/Java/Sbt application to Confluent Cloud Kafka cluster.
From Confluent I have the following configuration:

```
bootstrap.servers=xxxx.us-west1.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule   required username='{{ CLUSTER_API_KEY }}'   password='{{ CLUSTER_API_SECRET }}';
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
# Required for correctness in Apache Kafka clients prior to 2.6
client.dns.lookup=use_all_dns_ips

# Best practice for Kafka producer to prevent data loss
acks=all
```

Where and how would I configure it in Lagom?

Comment: Do any of these help? https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.6.x/java/KafkaClient.html#Alpakka-Kafka-configuration https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka-kafka/current/production.html

Answer (score 2):

I did manage to connect with the following configuration in my application.conf (thanks  @Robin Moffatt).

```
lagom.broker.kafka.service-name = ""
lagom.broker.kafka.brokers = "xxxx.us-west1.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092"

akka.kafka.consumer.kafka-clients {
    
    bootstrap.servers="xxxx.us-west1.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092"
    security.protocol="SASL_SSL"
    sasl.jaas.config="org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule   required username='API_KEY'   password='API_SECRET';"
    sasl.mechanism="PLAIN"
    client.dns.lookup="use_all_dns_ips"
}

akka.kafka.producer.kafka-clients {
    
    bootstrap.servers="xxxx.us-west1.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092"
    security.protocol="SASL_SSL"
    sasl.jaas.config="org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule   required username='API_KEY'   password='API_SECRET';"
    sasl.mechanism="PLAIN"
    client.dns.lookup="use_all_dns_ips"
}
```